# Has anybody successfully used the ODF "Simple API" from LotusScript to generate documents?

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotusscript, odf, ls2j

I'm trying to use LS2J to invoke the Simple API for the ODF Toolkit (https://incubator.apache.org/odftoolkit/simple/index.html) from LotusScript, and I've been unable to use it properly.

I've included in a Java library called ODFDOM the following:

- odfdom-java-0.8.7.jar
- simple-odf-v0.4.5.jar
- Xerces-J-bin.2.11.0-xml-schema-1.1-beta.zip

With this code in the Sub Initialize of the agent:

```
Dim js As javasession
Dim jc As Javaclass
Dim jerr As JAVAERROR
Dim jms As JavaMethodCollection
Dim jobj As Javaobject, jdoc As JavaObject
Dim jm As JAVAMETHOD

Set js = New JavaSession
Set jc = js.Getclass("org/odftoolkit/simple/SpreadsheetDocument")
Set jm = jc.GetMethod("newSpreadsheetDocument", "()Lorg/odftoolkit/simple/SpreadsheetDocument;")
Set jdoc = jm.Invoke
```

execution gives an error:

JS2J Error: Threw java.lang.NullPointerException

Any clues about what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to "Use" your library "ODFDOM" and get your class in Java notation with dots. You can shorten your code with direct call of your static method:

```
Use "ODFDOM"
Dim js As javasession
Dim jSpreadsheetDocumentClass As Javaclass
Dim jdoc As JavaObject

Set js = New JavaSession
Set jSpreadsheetDocumentClass  = js.Getclass("org.odftoolkit.simple.SpreadsheetDocument")
Set jdoc = jSpreadsheetDocumentClass.newSpreadsheetDocument()
```

UPDATE:

LS2J doesn't work with resources. Whenever you use resources in Java code it won't work with LS2J. After a short look into ODF Toolkit source code I saw resources used.

So, create an Java agent instead and call it from LotusScript.

Comment: I _did_ include **Use "ODFDOM"** in the Options section, I was just pasting code from Initialize. But it's a good point, though.


_When you use the dot "." notation on the Macintosh, the Mac will return an error that the Class cannot be found. Instead, use the slash "/" notation. The slash "/" notation works on all platforms. Use the slash "/" notation in your applications for multi-platform support._ (Designer manual)


I made the changes suggested, but the error is the same.

Comment: Ok, good to know, didn't developed for Mac yet. I worked a lot with LS2J and I think it won't work for ODF Toolkit. See my updated answer.